# WP8.1: AppBarButton.IsEnabled binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to bind IsEnabled property of AppBarButton to ToggleButton in XAML and it just doesn't work. There are no error messages or warnings. I can check or uncheck ToggleButton but nothing happens with AppBarButton. I have no idea where the problem is. Here's sample code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="button" Content="ToggleButton"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to your problem? I'm having (almost) the same problem right now.

Comment: Well, nope. I have noticed that TogleButton.IsChecked property is nullable bool and then I tried to use a converter but it didn't work either. So I made a workaround:

`AcceptCheckBox.Click += (s, a) =>
            {

                var conv = new NullableBoolToBoolConverter();

                AcceptButton.IsEnabled = (bool)conv.Convert(AcceptCheckBox.IsChecked, typeof(bool), null, "");

            };`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `DataContext` of the page is not active for the `BottomAppBar` or `TopAppBar`. Set the `DataContext` of the `CommandBar` manually to the `DataContext` of the Page.

Comment: I can set CommandBar's DataContext to a page or ToggleButton but it does not work either.